# How to check if RecyclerView lags?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Can I find any tools for checking if RecyclerView lags? For now I can't see the difference with empty item or item with bound view elements, but maybe on older devices this difference is more visible, especially it's hard to see without comparison if scrolling is really smooth.

Comment: There is a setting in the developer settings called 'Profile GPU rendering'. If you set it to 'On screen as bars' you see a threshold line and may bars that update with every UI update. I believe that when a bar exceeds the threshold, there is an operation that takes longer than the refresh rate of the screen. Perhaps it is useful to you

Comment: This option is very helpful, thank you.